# How to set Keras TimeseriesGenerator to predict the second next value?

Tags: keras

Currently I have the following code using `TimeseriesGenerator` from Keras:

```
TimeseriesGenerator(train, prediction, length=TIME_STEPS, batch_size=1)
```

Currently this shifts prediction one value backwards, so the train data for `t` will have the output of `t+1`. Which makes sense, but I want to predict t+2, thus train data for `t` will have the output of `t+2`.

Is there any way to do it using `TimeseriesGenerator`?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution is to just shift your predictions by 1, ie.:

```
TimeseriesGenerator(train[:-1], prediction[1:], length=TIME_STEPS, batch_size=1)
```

Note that you have to trim the train set, so both datasets have equal lengths.

You can also use the `timeseries_dataset_from_array` function where you can align the data and targets according to your needs as you can read in the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/timeseries/):

> **data**: Numpy array or eager tensor containing consecutive data points
> (timesteps). Axis 0 is expected to be the time dimension.
>
> **targets**:
> Targets corresponding to timesteps in data. It should have same length
> as data. targets[i] should be the target corresponding to the window
> that starts at index i (see example 2 below). Pass None if you don't
> have target data (in this case the dataset will only yield the input
> data).

So in your case it would be something like this:

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    train[:-TIME_STEPS-2],
    prediction[TIME_STEPS+2:],
    length=TIME_STEPS, 
    batch_size=1
)
```